# Eclipse remove version from project name

Tags: eclipse, maven

So in my eclipse, when I first "imported Maven project from filesystem", I accidentally used a name template like this: "[groupId]-[artifactId]-[version]"

Now my pom says version 1.1.7 but here's a screenshot of how it looks on my package manager?
[image]

Do I just have to reimport, or is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eclipse project name has no meaning to anyone but to the one viewing the project, it is not a folder name, but just project metadata in `.project` file.

You can Right Click your project, choose `maven` -> `Update Project` and it will update the project details & dependencies.

You can manually rename the project as well ( click `F2`, or right click -> rename )

Otherwise you can reimport; or simply edit the `.project` file and change the name.